# Existence of Sequence in Set of Real Numbers whose Limit is Infimum

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

> Let A⊆ℝ be a non-empty subset of the real numbers.
>
> Let b be an infimum of A.
>
> Then there exists a sequence $⟨a_n⟩$ in ℝ such that:
>
> (1): $∀n∈ℕ$:$a_n$∈A
>
> (2): $\lim_{n \to \infty}, a_n=b.$
>
> Proof From: Infimum of Subset of Real Numbers is Arbitrarily Close:
>
> **For ϵ=1/n there exists an $a_n$∈A such that:**
>
> $a_n−b<1/n$ Since $b$ is an infimum of $A$:
>
> $0≤a_n−b.$ Therefore:
>
> $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n=b.$

I don't understand why we set or know that epsilon is equal to $1/n$ as shown in bold. Can I get an explanation?Also,  How do we know that $a_n-b$ is greater than or equal to $0$?

Comment: Change the sentence into "for any positive integer $n$, there exists..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$1/n$ was chosen because it goes to monotonically to $0$.  Any nice sequence would work here.  $1/n^2$ or $1/n!$ etc.

Since $b$ is the infimum, it is less than or equal to all elements of $A$, so necessarily $a_n -b \geq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Whoever told us that $b=\inf A$ has promised us that for any real number $r \gt 0$, there is an element of $A$ in $[b,b+r)$.  We have chosen a series of $\epsilon$s and invoked this property.  This is just a convenient series of positive reals for the proof we want to do.  If you break it down into stages, we first said "You promised us there was an element of $A$ in $[b,b+1)$.  Please tell us one."  We then write that down as $a_1$.  Now we say "You promised us there was an element of $A$ in $[b,b+\frac 12)$.  Please tell us one." We then write that down as $a_2$ and so on.  This produces the sequence we want that converges to $b$.  We know that $b$ is less than or equal to all the elements of $A$ and all our $a_n$ are elements of $A$, so $a_n-b \ge 0$